# TypeScript Compiler Errors in gulp-typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I recently updated to Angular 2.4, and my `gulp-typescript` build step is throwing compiler errors. I've googled everything, and looked at every question I could find that seemed relevant. However, nothing has worked for me so far. I'm using `typescript` version 2.1.4 and `gulp-typescript` version 3.1.3. the following is the output with the compiler errors that I'm seeing.

```
/Users/pjlamb12/projects/service-portal/node_modules/@types/es6-shim/index.d.ts(6,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
/Users/pjlamb12/projects/service-portal/node_modules/@types/es6-shim/index.d.ts(10,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'value' must have identical modifiers.
/Users/pjlamb12/projects/service-portal/node_modules/@types/es6-shim/index.d.ts(248,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'EPSILON' must have identical modifiers.
/Users/pjlamb12/projects/service-portal/node_modules/@types/es6-shim/index.d.ts(283,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'MAX_SAFE_INTEGER' must have identical modifiers.
/Users/pjlamb12/projects/service-portal/node_modules/@types/es6-shim/index.d.ts(290,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'MIN_SAFE_INTEGER' must have identical modifiers.
/Users/pjlamb12/projects/service-portal/node_modules/@types/es6-shim/index.d.ts(346,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'flags' must have identical modifiers.
/Users/pjlamb12/projects/service-portal/node_modules/@types/es6-shim/index.d.ts(498,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical modifiers.
/Users/pjlamb12/projects/service-portal/node_modules/@types/es6-shim/index.d.ts(561,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'size' must have identical modifiers.
/Users/pjlamb12/projects/service-portal/node_modules/@types/es6-shim/index.d.ts(570,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical modifiers.
/Users/pjlamb12/projects/service-portal/node_modules/@types/es6-shim/index.d.ts(581,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'size' must have identical modifiers.
/Users/pjlamb12/projects/service-portal/node_modules/@types/es6-shim/index.d.ts(591,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical modifiers.
/Users/pjlamb12/projects/service-portal/node_modules/@types/es6-shim/index.d.ts(606,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical modifiers.
/Users/pjlamb12/projects/service-portal/node_modules/@types/es6-shim/index.d.ts(620,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical modifiers.
/Users/pjlamb12/projects/service-portal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts(21,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
```

All the errors are in the node_modules file. `gulp-typescript` is being configured like this:

```
tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', { typescript: require('typescript') });
```

and the `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "version": "1.8.9",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
},
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "typings/main",
        "typings/main.d.ts",
        ".tmp"
    ]
}
```

I have the `node_modules` directory in the `exclude` array, but it appears to still be included. I read on one answer that any referenced file is compiled, regardless of if it's in the `exclude` array or not.

Is there anything I can do to get rid of these compiler errors? Or are they things I can ignore and will be fixed by the maintainers of the packages?

Thanks!